# Want Decimal Values without round off

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some data to calculate 
I want to get values without round off after calculation
suppose :::::::

I want Column A1(3.4) multiply with Column A2(4.834)
like

- **A1(3.4)*A2(4.834) and answer is in A3=16.4356**
  EXACT VALUE BECOMES 16.4356, when i reduce decimal value to 2 it shows 16.44, But i wnat it should be 16.43 instead of 16.44
  it gives the round off value 
  """"""""""""""""""""""""""pls solve this"""""""""""""""""""""""""""

Comment: If you are just reducing decimals in the format, the value in the cell will still be `16.4356`.  If you want the value in the cell to be `16.43`, you will need to use the `TRUNC` function.

Comment: Use this `=ROUNDDOWN(A1*A2,2)` ,, you get `16.43`.